# Is this price right?

Tags: hardware

I am not sure if this is the right place for this, but I do feel as if it is related.

I recently bought what I was told is a server from a local Computer Shop. In total the price is £225. I have currently paid £180, and so owe £45. I at the time was desperate for a PC, mainly because of School Work, but also because I had just started to get into web development, and thought that this PC\Server would be a decent place to start.

Now I have had it home for a month or so, the performance of it is really starting to get to me, since I was expecting a much greater experience, It also didn't help that the people in the shop were covering the mud with sugar by telling me this is great that does this etc.

I have put the specs of the device below (obtained through [speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy)) and I'm hoping someone can tell me if I have been ripped off or if I have paid a decent price, the most important factor I believe is the PC\Server is Second Hand.

- CPU:                  Intel Xeon 3.20GHz -- Irwindale
- RAM:                 2GB DDR (it says 2GB physical and 4GB virtual)
- Motherboard:    Supermicro X6DAL
- Graphics:          NVIDIA GeForce 210 (Revision A3; Mem: 512MB)
- Storage:            SAMSUNG HD250HJ ATA (Main Drive in 2 partitions)
- Optical Drives:   HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GH10L ATA
- Sound Card:      NVIDIA High Definition Audio (Yup, that's all it says)
- Network:            ADD-GWP110v4 PCI Wireless LAN Card | Intel PRO/1000 MT Network Conx.

And very kindly they put in a faulty multi-card reader

This is not my area of intelligence I struggle with knwing the value of tech, I just need to know If I should try to talk to them about the price or if it is worth it.

---

**P.S.** Small extra question how hot should I allow it (The whole thing in general) to get before worrying?

Comment: This is gonna get closed, but you need more than 2GB of ram.. that's the bare minimum

Comment: @ekaj Sorry, but do you have any idea if it is worth £225 ? I have seen gaming Pcs built for around the same price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you kinda got ripped off. The system seems to be ~10 years old (the CPU  is from 2005) and as far as I know from buying used server hardware in Germany, you could get a decent ~5 year old HP system or the like for the same price. I don't know whether prices for used hardware are higher in the UK in general, but over here that would be definitely too much. I would give such a system away for free.

Just do a quick online search (ebay?). You should find plenty of newer machines for the same price. You really don't need a server for some web development and school work.

According to Intel's [spec page](http://ark.intel.com/products/28017/64-bit-Intel-Xeon-Processor-3_20-GHz-2M-Cache-800-MHz-FSB) the maximum design temperature of the CPU is 72 C, so keep it below that.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling that I might have jumped the gun and fell in a pit, Is there anything I can do about the money, or is that too much off-topic. (Huge thanks for the temp, I get scared if it goes above 50 C, I can rest a bit now)

Comment: I think this more about general life advice... :)

I would try to return it, if you just bought it, but I would also not be too surprised if they don't take it back.

Comment: Also you know it's got just a single core with no hyperthreading,the memory will be slow, as will the small disk - actually one of the new Raspberry Pi's would be quicker! i'm in the UK too and would happily help to fight your corner on this, just ask ok.

Comment: I don't know about ripped-off, mis-sold perhaps. Budget second-hand computers are simply not good value. Almost _any_ machine is suitable for `School Work [plus] web development` - e.g. [same price, new budget notebook things](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Acer-Aspire-ES1-512-15-6-inch-Notebook/dp/B00OA4YJZO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1426335044&sr=8-1&keywords=acer+laptop).

Comment: @Chopper3 I am going to try talking to the guys at the computer shop, see what they have to say. I will get back to you as soon as I can. And huge thanks for offering to help, I think I might just end up needing it. As for the RPi, I have on and have been using it more and more than the PC in question.